# Need to print empty dictionary as {} instead of null in jsoncpp

Tags: c++, dictionary, jsoncpp

I have a slight issue with jsoncpp.  I'm building a list of dictionaries and if a dictionary is empty and I print the result of the list using writer I get

```
[{some value}, null].
```

How do I make writer print `{}` instead of `null`?

Comment: AFAIK a default constructed Json::Value will be output as {}

Answer (score 2):

### Solution

Use the `Json::Value` constructor which takes one argument `Json::ValueType::objectValue` (as described in the documentation: [JsonCpp Doc/Json::Value](http://open-source-parsers.github.io/jsoncpp-docs/doxygen/class_json_1_1_value.html#ada6ba1369448fb0240bccc36efaa46f7)).

### Example

```
Json::Value value;
value["list"][0] = Json::Value(Json::ValueType::objectValue);
value["list"][1] = Json::Value();
cout << value.toStyledString() << endl;
```

The above code prints out:

```
{
   "list" : [ {}, null ]
}
```

### Explanation

The default constructor for the `Json::Value` class uses the default parameter value `Json::ValueType::nullType`. The `Json::Writer` class family displays value with `nullType` as `null` and
an empty value with type `objectValue` as `{}` (true for every `Json::Writer`: `StyledWriter`, `StyledStreamWriter`, `FastWriter`.

- `Json::Value`'s defualt constructor, line 212 [Json/value.h@github](https://github.com/open-source-parsers/jsoncpp/blob/master/include/json/value.h#L212):

  ```
   namespace Json {
     class JSON_API Value {
       Value(ValueType type = nullValue);  // line: 212
       (...)
  ```
- Here `StyledWriter` in action, lines 263-290 [json_writer.cpp@github](https://github.com/open-source-parsers/jsoncpp/blob/master/src/lib_json/json_writer.cpp#L263-L290):

  ```
   void StyledWriter::writeValue(const Value& value) {
     switch (value.type()) {
       case nullValue:
         pushValue("null");
         (...)
       case objectValue: {
         Value::Members members(value.getMemberNames());
         if (members.empty())
           pushValue("{}");
           (...)
  ```